# how to forward snmpget request to remote machine and get the response

Tags: snmp4j

I am using snmp4j java API's and implemented AgentServer by extending BaseAgent and extended CommandProcessor to get the snmp request.
I am getting the snmp request in processrequest successfully. 
I have overridden dispactchCommand() method to dispatch the command to super class commandprocessor.
Once i receive the request I need to change the OID and send the snmpget request to remote machine and get the response from the remote machine.
ie) i tried to forward the request to remote machine and get back the response.

Thanks 
Shriram

Comment: finally found solution..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MOSubtreeProxy to easily implement a proxy to another agent for an OID subtree.  Together with the Snmp4jProxyMib you can even configure it at runtime using SNMP and the SNMP4J-PROXY-MIB coming with SNMP4J-Agent.